# Remove "Category:" from Post meta

Tags: categories, post-meta

I need to remove the word "Category:" from in front of the actual category name/link. I have checked every answer here and on other sites, and none of the answers work on my site...I have tried many different snippets in my functions.php file and none have worked.

Site URL is

https://robinreport.staging.wpengine.com/

Theme is Bizbudding Mai Lifestyle

Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress StackExchange, the "Bizbudding Mai Lifestyle" theme is a commerical theme. Normaly when you buy such a theme you buy also some support. It would be best if you contact the Bizbuddy support directly with your question.

Comment: It's hard to suggest any answer for a premium theme like that unless have access to the backend of the website. So you should contact the support staff of the theme.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments - I have contacted them, and am waiting on a response, but was hoping that I might find someone here that had some experience with this. Excuse me for approaching this forum...I didn't realize it was only for non-commercial themes and questions. And I do have access to the entire backend of the website as I built and host the site.